# Why doesn't an undefined name in an "except" raise a NameError?

Tags: python

I was surprised today to see that the following works with no exceptions (in Python 2.7.3 at least):

```
>>> try:
...     pass
... except ThingThatDoesNotExist:
...     print "bad"
...
>>>
```

I would have thought that this should raise a `NameError` in the REPL, similar to how the following would:

```
>>> x = ThingThatDoesNotExist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ThingThatDoesNotExist' is not defined
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Your test tries nothing, and therefore passes. Since it does, it never runs over the except clause. I might be mistaken, but doesn't Python ignore undefined variables until they are evaluated?

Comment: That's exactly what's going on here. Python doesn't check if that name is bound to anything until it needs to.

Comment: Yup. Just change the `pass` to `raise ValueError` or something and you'll get the `NameError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same reason this does not raise a exception:

```
>>> True or ThingThatDoesNotExist
```

Python looks up names exactly the moment they need to be evaluated. Names that don't need to be evaluated are not looked up and it's the failed lookup that raises the exception.

Comment: In retrospect -- yes, this makes perfect sense. I think I am suffering from not enough coffee at this point :)